# How to extract zip file which exist on the local machine to the partition on the server?

Tags: java, file, directory, zip, extract

I have a zip file on the local machine in the C:\tem\test directory. I want to extract it on the server in the new directory which should have same name as zip file. how can i do it?

```
class UnZipFile {
final static File source = new File("C:\\tmp\\test\\R1112B2_BcfiHtm.zip");

public static void getZipFiles() {
    try {
        String destination ="U:\\root\\intranet\\res\\fi\\test";
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        ZipInputStream zipinputstream = null;
        ZipEntry zipentry;
        zipinputstream = new ZipInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(source));

        zipentry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry();
        while (zipentry != null) {
            //for each entry to be extracted
            String entryName = zipentry.getName();
            System.out.println("entryname " + entryName);
            int n;
            FileOutputStream fileoutputstream;
            File newFile = new File(entryName);
            String directory = newFile.getParent();

            if (directory == null) {
                if (newFile.isDirectory())
                    break;
            }

            fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(
                    destination + entryName);

            while ((n = zipinputstream.read(buf, 0, 1024)) > -1)
                fileoutputstream.write(buf, 0, n);

            fileoutputstream.close();
            zipinputstream.closeEntry();
            zipentry = zipinputstream.getNextEntry();

        }//while

        zipinputstream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

**I get following exception:**
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\tmp\test\Attestn\1000100_FormDem_NS_NL.pdf (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Your code is showing that you want to extract zip file while your error is saying that it is looking for some PDF file, how it is possible?

Comment: Have you verified, that the source file exists and is readable?

Comment: A sidenote: in `if (newFile.isDirectory()) break; ` do you really want to end the loop or just skip that zip entry (in which case you'd need a `continue;` instead of `break;`)?

Comment: Also: can you please post the line (or mark it, note that we won't count lines) you're getting the exception on?

Comment: My zip file contains file and directory.I want to create directory if content of zip has directory if not just create the file.